# generate/insert contiguous numbers to elements in a Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Suppose I have a RDD loaded by 
`lines = sc.textFile('/test.txt')`
 and RDD is like `['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`. Then I would like to generate RDD `[(0, 'apple'), (1, 'orange'), (2, 'banana')]`.

I know this could be done by `indexed_lines = lines.zipWithIndex().map(lambda (x, y): ','.join([str(y), x])).collect()`

But now I have another RDD `new_lines = ['pineapple','blueberry']`, I would like to `union` these two RDDs(indexed_lines and new_lines) to construct `[(0, 'apple'), (1, 'orange'), (2, 'banana'), (3, 'pineapple'), (4, 'blueberry')]` notice that the indexed_lines already exists and I don't want to change the data within it.

I am trying to `zip and union` RDDs 
`index = sc.parallelize(range(3, 5))
new_indexed_lines = new_lines.zip(index)`
but it broke in this `zip` transform.

Any idea why it is broken and if there is a smarter way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
offset = lines.count()
new_indexed_lines = (new_lines
  .zipWithIndex()
  .map(lambda xi: (xi[1] + offset, xi[0])))
```